# "You found" vs. "You've found" in context

Tags: tense

Imagine that, I was confusing concept A with concept B. I searched and found their definitions but was still confused. So I raised a question, and then someone replied

> You **found** the definition of concept A, so why would you think it involves concept B?

I guess they were trying to emphasize the fact I have got the definition of concept A and I would not be confused them.

To express that indication, is it more appropriate to use "**you've found**" here?

---

Above is the simplified version, here is what actually happened.

I was confused cornea with retina. So, I put forward a question in a [post](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/22808/17920)

> ... is astigmatism a type of retinopathy?

A contributor replied me in this way

> You observed that astigmatism is caused by a misshaped cornea, so why would you think it involves the retina?

I guess "you observed" is more appropriate to convey the fact that I've already found that definition.

---

Is my understanding right? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your usage of the word 'find' is unusual in this context. The Cambridge Dictionary lists three meanings: discover, feel and judge. The most widely used meaning is discover- like "I found a gold ring on my way to work". Which meaning did you have in mind, because some meanings are more stative than others. Bear in mind also that US vs UK  usages are different: Americans are generally less likely to use present perfect.

Comment: @JavaLatte Thank you. So, "you observed ..." is perfectly grammatical and idiomatic, right?

Comment: @JavaLatte "Felt" and "judged" aren't applicable as definitions of *found* in *You('ve) found the definition of A*.

Comment: @JavaLatte I guess I din't express that clearly. I actively searched and got their definitions. Is it still unusual in this kind of situation?

Comment: If I say "I found the definition of that word", it means that I looked in the dictionary and was able to locate it. It doesn't actually mean that I read the definition, or understood it, or that I accept or believe the definition.  So, finding a definition of A doesn't imply at all that I read, understand or accept that definition. I does not  in any way preclude my thinking  that it involves concept B.

Comment: @JavaLatte Thanks for your comprehensive explanation. How about "observed"?

Comment: Past simple "You observed" means that you saw something in the past. Present perfect "You have observed" means that you saw and understood something and retained that information until the present time.